# CodeIgniter Api methods working on localhost, but not on production (URL issue)

Tags: angularjs, codeigniter, api, rest

I developed a REST API using CodeIgniter and consumed it using AngularJS. Everything works fine on localhost, but when I put it on production, I get a File Not Found error when I call my API method:

[Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tYEEa.jpg) (`localhost` on the left, Production on the right)

Is it related to .htaccess file or it could be port issue?

Here is my .htaccess file under \www\ci-3_todo:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
```

Comment: Is your production server running Apache? What method is PHP being executed, e.g. mod_php, FastCGI, PHPFPM, etc? If you're running Apache, is it configured to allow overrides?

Comment: @kfriend , thank you for the quick response, Yes our server running Apache, and the php_method I think it's FPM/FastCGI, no idea how to check if the server allow overrides

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try hitting this url it works.

promoter.capesolution.tn/ce/ci-3_todo/index.php/ApiRoutes/routes

Cheers

Comment: Thank you so much , I changed my angularjs call from : $http.get('ApiRoutes/routes')   To :  $http.get('/ce/ci-3_todo/index.php/ApiRoutes/routes')  , It's working now,  I thought I removed the "index.php" from the URL via .htaccess , it seems my apache server doesn't allow the overrides as @kfriend said

Comment: yes that might be a reason if you are using shared hosting. Anyways, Cheers !!

Answer (score 0):

use lowercase word for URL and test again